# Using grouped value instead of table value in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to group some data by date, but I have a very special case where the name of the final field should be the same of the original field and I can't use an expression in the `GROUP BY`

I have created this sqlfiddle with some example data:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8771a/1

I need this result:

```
DATE    PAGEVIEWS
2013-12 69
2013-11 70
```

**Note 1**: I can't change the group by, if I do this I get the result, but I need to group by `date` and date should be the formatted date, and not the real date in the table:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m") AS `date`, SUM(pageviews) AS pageviews
FROM `domains_data`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m")
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

**Note 2**: I can't rename the field, it should have the name "date" at the end, this isn't possible for me:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m") AS `date2`, SUM(pageviews) AS pageviews
FROM `domains_data`
GROUP BY `date2`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

There is some way to do it with MySQL?

Comment: I don't understand, your first query is returning what you want, isn't it? [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8771a/5)

Comment: Yes, and the second too, but I can't change the `group by` for an expression, I can just change the SELECT expression, the rest is already written and I can't modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the use of nested query allowed?

```
SELECT `date`, SUM(pageviews) AS pageviews FROM
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m") AS `date`, SUM(pageviews) AS pageviews
    FROM `domains_data`
    GROUP BY `date`) AS Ref
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Comment: Yes, it is, I can change the FROM and use nested query. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the `from` clause:

```
SELECT `date`, SUM(pageviews) AS pageviews
FROM (select  DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m") AS `date`, pageviews
      from `domains_data` dd
     ) dd
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date` DESC;
```

However, given the constraint that you cannot change the `group by`, you probably cannot change the `from` either.  Can you explain why your query has these limitations?

Comment: I can't change the name of the field because the result goes to a view to show the result and I can't change the group by because all the queries get the same group by after. Your solution it's good, thanks.